# CircleCI timing out when installing CocoaPods for React Native Project

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, circleci

Trying to push out an iOS release to Testflight through CircleCI. We've been doing this for months and everything has worked great until we've upgraded to React Native 0.63.3.

Now when we try to build our IPA file, CircleCI times out when trying to fetch CocoaPods. In our config.yml file, we are hitting this URL:

```
  - run:
      name: Install CocoaPods
      command: |
        curl https://cocoapods-specs.circleci.com/fetch-cocoapods-repo-from-s3.sh | bash -s cf
        cd ios && pod install
```

however this cocoapods S3 URL seems to be out of date and CircleCI is recommending we put the `source https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` at the top of our podfile. However, CircleCI doesnt seem to pick that up even when we push a new build if we remove the code above from our config.yml file. Also replacing the old specs S3 URL with the CDN url fails as well.

My question is how do I get CircleCI to see the `source https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` in our podfile OR what is the correct URL I can put in our config.yml file that wont timeout?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem exactly but instead of manually downloading cocoapods, you can use Gemfile with `gem 'cocoapods'` (or just run `gem install cocoapods`) and install just like any other Ruby project (and while we're at it you could also add fastlane which I highly recommend).